# Fit Child Div Inside Parent Div on Hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a child div that needs to be displayed on top of its parent when hovered. The child div doesnt seem to respect the parent's div padding restraints and is therefore bigger.

I have found that I can use the margin instead of padding on the parent, however this breaks the bootstrap column layout and forces the 3rd div into the next row which is not desirable.

To summarize: how do a make the hovered div the same width as its parent w/o using margin instead of padding?

http://jsfiddle.net/tu40thL8/3/

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="search-result">
    <div class="row" id="searchResults">
        <div id="result-list" class="results">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 resultsinner">
                <div class="result resultSolidHover">DIV1 TEXT</div>
                <div class="resultHoverButton"> <a href="#" class="viewButton">VIEW</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 resultsinner">
                <div class="result resultSolidHover">DIV2 TEXT</div>
                <div class="resultHoverButton"> <a href="#" class="viewButton">VIEW</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 resultsinner">
                <div class="result resultSolidHover">DIV3 TEXT</div>
                <div class="resultHoverButton"> <a href="#" class="viewButton">VIEW</a>
LALALAL</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.resultHoverButton {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #364048;
    background-size: cover;
}
.resultsinner:hover .resultHoverButton {
    display:block !important;
    visibility:visible !important;
}
.resultSolidHover {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:0 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Check out border-box http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: instead width/height:100%; use coordonates to size it and mind the padding value , 1em i guess: http://jsfiddle.net/tu40thL8/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to get the behaviour you desire.

1. You can show/hide the relevant element on hover; http://jsfiddle.net/tu40thL8/15/. [**PREFERRED OPTION**]
2. Define the correct absolute positioning on hover in correlation with Bootstrap padding(`15px`); http://jsfiddle.net/tu40thL8/17/.

Option 1 is simplest and decouples you from Bootstraps implementation. With this option when you hover you hide `.resultSolidHover`

```
.resultsinner:hover .resultSolidHover {
    display:none;
}
```

This allows you to take out all of the absolute positioning defined for `resultHoverButton` as follows;

```
.resultHoverButton {
    display: none;
    background-color: #364048;
}
```

Option 2 relies on getting your absolute positioning correct. Bootstrap defines padding for columns of `15px`. This means when you absolute position your hover button it needs to have a `left` and `right` of `15px`. Simply changing the class definition for `resultHoverButton` to;

```
.resultHoverButton {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #364048;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please don't put links pointing to your personal blog / github account in your answers.  Those are reserved for your user profile!

Comment: Sorry, that's fair. It's habit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are doing what you want by positioning it absolutely. Absolute position will move it out of the flow and be guided by the `left`, `top` etc. positions. And, why are you using `visibility` here, really not required at all.

Keep it simple and do it this way, by just changing the `display` on hover for both children:

```
.resultHoverButton {
    display: none;
    background-color: #364048;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.resultSolidHover {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.resultsinner:hover .resultSolidHover {
    display:none;
}
.resultsinner:hover .resultHoverButton {
    display:block;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tu40thL8/10/

Answer (score 1):

[Example Codepen](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/KdPKMb)

Hello check this one out, i'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
<div class="resultOut">
     <div class="resultInner"><h1>Hello World!</h1></div>
</div>

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.resultOut{
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}

.resultInner{
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}

.resultOut:hover .resultInner{
  visibility:visible;
}

.resultInner h1{
  text-align:center;
  line-height:200px;
}
```